# Get shared image from chrome in my app cusses permission denial exception

Tags: android

In my android application I am trying to **get shared image** from **chrome** browser and when I open an `inputStream` from the `Url` that I got from `intent` an exception happens.

for a clear question I made a new project and put all needed codes inside of an `activity` and my **reference** is [android documentations from here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive)

I copied all functions from the reference and just added a simple line to open an `imputStream` form the `Url`.

now my activity is like this :

```
public class ActShare extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);

        handleIncomeIntent();
    }

    private void handleIncomeIntent() {
        // Get intent, action and MIME type
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
            } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
                handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
            }
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
                handleSendMultipleImages(intent); // Handle multiple images being sent
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Got some kind of files.");
        }
    }

    void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
        String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (sharedText != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Got some text.");
        }
    }

    void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
        Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (imageUri != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Got some image.");
            try {
                InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri); // the line that exception happens
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    void handleSendMultipleImages(Intent intent) {
        ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (imageUris != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Got some multiple Images.");
        }
    }
}
```

and the **log** of **exception** is here:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ir.greentouchsoft.testproject, PID: 29462
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.greentouchsoft.testproject/ir.greentouchsoft.testproject.ActShare}:
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider org.chromium.chrome.browser.util.ChromeFileProvider from ProcessRecord{44f12770 29462:ir.greentouchsoft.testproject/u0a127} (pid=29462, uid=10127) that is not exported from uid 10032
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5314)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:680)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider org.chromium.chrome.browser.util.ChromeFileProvider from ProcessRecord{44f12770 29462:ir.greentouchsoft.testproject/u0a127} (pid=29462, uid=10127) that is not exported from uid 10032
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1468)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1422)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2865)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4684)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2315)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1459)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1057)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:914)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:639)
        at ir.greentouchsoft.testproject.ActShare.handleSendImage(ActShare.java:54)
        at ir.greentouchsoft.testproject.ActShare.onCreate(ActShare.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5285)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
```

this problem is happening **just** in `android 4.4.2` (testing on `mate7` smartphone) and in other version of android is **clearly working**.

in my tests **there is no problem** when I get shared images from **any other application**(like whatsApp or telegram)

I found **some solution** about get and use the `url` in j**ust one activity** to solve problem and as you see I just implemented the functions in just one activity.